# Removing players from teams?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do you remove players from teams? I have tried `scoreboard remove`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 4):

The command you're looking for is `/scoreboard teams leave playername`. This will remove the selected player from whichever team they're on. For more reference on scoreboard commands, the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard) is an excellent resource.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/team leave playername`